# Assign R.id to dynamically created Edit Text

Tags: android

I am new to this. wanted to know if there is a way to assign R.id to dynamically created edit text so i can move the data with in to SQLite db. tried few diff ways but fail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android *id* should be unique. Setting any arbitrary integer value can lead to duplicate ids. The correct way is to define *id* like below.

Create a new xml file named `ids.xml` inside `res/values` folder.

Add new item like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="button_group_cancel" />
</resources>
```

Now you can set the id to edittext as:

```
edittext.setId(R.id.button_group_cancel);
```

Comment: The id has to be unique for programmatically created id's and R.id's independently. They can have duplicates between the two of them though. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)

Comment: @TronicZomB thanks. :) My answer highlighted how to create ids.. Since the question is how to set `R.id` programatically and not an `int`.

Comment: Yea, I just wanted to point out that there can be the discrepancy between id's set in java and id's set in R.java. Though I am not sure about id's set in ids.xml... Though `R.id` is nothing more than a reference to an `int`.

Comment: Hi when I am looping it to multiple edittext and try to get id by editText.getId(); it is returning same id for view. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an id using `.setId(int)` before you add the EditText to the layout. However this does not place the id into the R.java file.

You can reference the EditText with `findViewById(int)` instead of using `findViewById(R.id.editTextId)`, where int is the same int used in the set method.